# "YouTube High Definition" add-on self-installed without my permission, malware?

Tags: firefox, malware, youtube

I came back from a brief trip to the store and there was a new tab open in my Firefox browser (This site: `http://barisderin.com/`), announcing that the "YouTube High Definition" had been "installed". I have never had this add-on installed on my machine before, nor did I ask to install it. My questions are:

- Is Mozilla/Firefox installing this Add-On on user PCs without user permission?
- The only add-ons I have deliberately installed in my browser are Grease Monkey, No Script, and User Agent Switcher. Did one of these three add-ons install the mystery add-on?
- If it was not installed by one of the above components, how could it have spontaneously installed itself on my machine?
- Is this add-on a known malware vector?

Comment: Your link is confusing.  I see no relevant information or even a mention, to YouTube on it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is Mozilla/Firefox installing this Add-On on user PCs without user
>   permission?

No.

> The only add-ons I have deliberately installed in my browser are Grease Monkey, No Script, and User Agent Switcher. Did one of these three add-ons install the mystery add-on?

No.

> If it was not installed by one of the above components, how could it have spontaneously installed itself on my machine?

It didn't.

It could have been:

- Installed before in the same machine and new opened tab was due to an update, not installation.
- Installed in any other machine where you used Firefox sync.

> Is this add-on a known malware vector?

Unlikely*.

- If it's featured in the Mozilla addons store, reviewed, etc. it's tremendously unlikely (but not impossible) it being malware or malware vector.

Comment: It is in the Mozilla addons store.

Comment: @user3169 I know ;) , hence the "tremendously". It's not impossible though. But not the case here. It was installed by the user or someone else with access to the PC or synced from another PC due to Firefox sync. The rest is just paranoia.